# Unable to specify FILLFACTOR on clustered index in SQL Server (ANSI_PADDING error)

Tags: sql-server, clustered-index, fillfactor

Why can't `FILLFACTOR` be set on a clustered index with `PERSISTED NOT NULL` computed columns?

Query to set `FILLFACTOR`:

```
ALTER INDEX [PK_MyIndex] ON [MyTable] REBUILD PARTITION=ALL WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90)
```

Error:

```
ALTER INDEX failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_PADDING'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.
```

Is it possible to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the following article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187403.aspx

> SET ANSI_PADDING must be ON when you are creating or changing indexes
>   on computed columns or indexed views. For more information about
>   required SET option settings with indexed views and indexes on
>   computed columns, see "Considerations When You Use the SET Statements"
>   in SET Statements (Transact-SQL).

Try the following statement:

```
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
ALTER INDEX [PK_MyIndex] ON [MyTable] REBUILD PARTITION=ALL WITH (FILLFACTOR = 90)
```

Comment: Thank you! I had it in my mind that I had to set the ANSI_PADDING as on the table.